# How to check if an array contains all the elements of another array? If not, output the missing elements

Tags: python, numpy

I need to check if an array A contains all elements of another array B. If not, output the missing elements. Both A and B are integers, and B is always from 0 to N with an interval of 1.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,3,6,7,8,9])
B=np.arange(10)
```

I know that I can use the following to check if there is any missing elements, but it does not give the index of the missing element.

```
np.all(elem in A  for elem in B)
```

Is there a good way in python to output the indices of the missing elements?

Comment: At start it says `output the missing elements` and then it says `to output the indices of the missing elements`. These are two different things. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, it should be output the indices of the missing elements, but since the array B values from 0 to N, so it is the same as the indices.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can try the following and assuming that B always is an "index" list:

```py
[i for i in B if i not in A]
```

The output would be : [0, 4, 5]

#### Best way to do it with numpy

Numpy actually has a function to perform this : [numpy.insetdiff1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

```py
np.setdiff1d(B, A)

# Which returns
array([0, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to get both index and content of a list. The following code would do what you want

```py
    idx = [idx for idx, element in enumerate(B) if element not in A]
```

Comment: This wont work because we want to check elements of B that are not in A. You should edit to do the opposite. All elements of A will be in B, so idx will always be an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming we want to get the elements exclusive to `B`, when compared to `A`.

**Approach #1**

Given the specific of  `B is always from 0 to N with an interval of 1`, we can use a simple mask-based one -

```
mask = np.ones(len(B), dtype=bool)
mask[A] = False
out = B[mask]
```

**Approach #2**

Another one that edits `B` and would be more memory-efficient -

```
B[A] = -1
out = B[B>=0]
```

**Approach #3**

A more generic case of integers could be handled differently -

```
def setdiff_for_ints(B, A):
    N = max(B.max(), A.max()) - min(min(A.min(),B.min()),0) + 1
    mask = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
    mask[B] = True
    mask[A] = False
    out = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [77]: A
Out[77]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  6,  7,  8, -6])

In [78]: B
Out[78]: array([1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9])

In [79]: setdiff_for_ints(B, A)
Out[79]: array([4, 5, 9])

# Using np.setdiff1d to verify :
In [80]: np.setdiff1d(B, A)
Out[80]: array([4, 5, 9])
```

Timings -

```
In [81]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: A = np.unique(np.random.randint(-10000,100000,1000000))
    ...: B = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,100000,1000000))

# @Hugolmn's soln with np.setdiff1d
In [82]: %timeit np.setdiff1d(B, A)
4.78 ms ± 96.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [83]: %timeit setdiff_for_ints(B, A)
599 µs ± 6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: A major issue I see with the 3rd approach is that `mask[B] = True` won't work when `B.max()` is bigger than `N`. You need to add 0 in `min(A.min(),B.min())`. In addition, it will be become much slower as the sparsity increases, as well as when the values are getting larger. With an upper bound of `1e9` and 100 values in each list, the performance gap is tremendous: 1.32 µs vs 46.4 ms (roughly x 50 000)

Comment: @Hugolmn Ah yeah, good catch. I needed to add `min(..,0)` there. Thanks! Yup surely dependent on the sparsity.